# ¿Cómo capturar que elemento fue pulsado? JS

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero capturar cual de las imágenes fue pulsada para así en el visor poder cambiar la imagen y el figcaption. Pero debo hacerlo con los eventos de campo semántico y sin tocar el html que ya tengo.

Es decir, que sea con el `window.onload` y capture en cual de las imágenes esta haciendo el `onclick`.

Gracias.

```js
window.onload = function() 
{
  let elemento = document.querySelectorAll("aside > img");
  elemento.onclick = function()
  {
    cambiarImagen(this);
  }

  function cambiarImagen(param)
  {
    document.getElementsByTagName("img")[5].src = param.src;
    document.getElementsByTagName("figcaption")[0].innerHTML = param.alt;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Visor de imágenes</h1>
    <aside id="parte_lateral">
      <img src="imagen1.jpeg" alt="Descripción imagen 1">
      <img src="imagen2.jpg" alt="Descripción imagen 2">
      <img src="imagen3.jpg" alt="Descripción imagen 3">
      <img src="imagen4.jpg" alt="Descripción imagen 4">
      <img src="imagen5.jpg" alt="Descripción imagen 5">
    </aside>
    <section id="parte_central">
      <figure>
        <img src="imagen1.jpeg" alt="Descripción imagen 1">
        <figcaption>Descripción imagen 1</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la pregunta, pero porque no intentas  agregar una propiedad o atributo con cierto nombre que diferencie la imagen, y a la hora de dar clic obtienes ese valor para comparar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al seleccionar con `.querySelectorAll` se está creando un array de las etiquetas seleccionadas, por lo tanto debes recorrer dicho array, en este caso uso un `forEach` después se le asigna el evento onclick a cada iteración, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
let elementosImg = document.querySelectorAll("#parte_lateral img");

  
       elementosImg.forEach(img=>{
       
     
       img.onclick = function(){
       document.getElementsByTagName("img")[5].src = this.src;
       document.getElementsByTagName("img")[5].alt = this.alt;
    document.getElementsByTagName("figcaption")[0].innerHTML = this.alt;
       
       }
     
       })
```

```html
<html>
<body>
 <h1>Visor de imágenes</h1>
 <aside id="parte_lateral">
  <img src="imagen1.jpeg" alt="Descripción imagen 1">
  <img src="imagen2.jpg" alt="Descripción imagen 2">
  <img src="imagen3.jpg" alt="Descripción imagen 3">
  <img src="imagen4.jpg" alt="Descripción imagen 4">
  <img src="imagen5.jpg" alt="Descripción imagen 5">
 </aside>
 <section id="parte_central">
  <figure>
   <img src="imagen1.jpeg" alt="Descripción imagen 1">
   <figcaption>Descripción imagen 1</figcaption>
  </figure>
 </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es exactamente lo que quería para el ejercicio.

Comment: No hay de que! Excelente día. :)

Comment: Perdona una pregunta. esta sentencia  elementosImg.forEach(img=> no la entiendo muy bien. Estoy acostumbrado a hacer foreach más "normales". En plan for (variable in objeto) { ... }

Comment: Aquí hay información de cómo funciona el [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo el porque de tus requerimientos pero aqui esta:

```
 document.querySelectorAll('aside > img').forEach(
  el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        console.log('your clicked element', e.srcElement);
        this.changeImage(e.srcElement); // funcion que cambia la imagen
      }
    );
  });
```

Con query selector seleccionas todos los elementos img del documento, luego por cada elemento seleccionado anades un "escuchador" por cada click en dicho elemento. Entonces cuando se produce el click obtienes la propiedad del elemento que en este caso es e.srcElement puedes verlo accediendo a la consola de desarrollador de tu browser.

Comment: Serviría que explicaras un poco más sobre lo que estás haciendo y por qué lo haces así para que haya un mejor entendimiento

Comment: Es que es un ejercicio de clase y tampoco sabia mucho más que explicar y además me dice el profe que sin el addEventListener ya que aun no lo hemos dado jeje.

Comment: entonces tienes que estudiar mas porque solo tu sabes las funciones que te han ensenado en clases